# Source for Gemara about Gedalia

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

Where can I find the Gemara which [this speaker](http://youtu.be/wa0vNInQiyg?t=3m25s) is talking about
? In short, he quotes a Gemara which talks about Gedalia. Gedalia heard that Yishmael was coming to murder the people of the town but didn't do anything. Therefore, Gedalia was called the murderer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gemara  can be found in [Niddah 61a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=61&format=pdf).